# Dll does not seem to be read, why?

Tags: c#, .net, object, constructor, instantiation

I am creating a application form to view/change a tag from a software called InTouch.

I added the dll as a reference and I would like to use the `Read(string tagName`) fct in the IOM.InTouchDataAccess.  VS does not see the fct Read when I write `InTouchWrapper TagType = new read()`. It only sees InTouchWrapper as I wrote in the code which gives me the error `IOM.InTouchDataAccess.InTouchWrapper' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments`

I don't understand why is this happening. I am running the InTouch software while coding, maybe there is an access conflict with the software.

**MyCode**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using IOM.InTouchDataAccess;

namespace TagBrowser
{
    public partial class TagBrowser : Form
    {
        public TagBrowser()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TagBrowser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void TagBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void TypeBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InTouchWrapper TagType = new InTouchWrapper();
        }
```

**The dll**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using NDde.Client;

namespace IOM.InTouchDataAccess
{
    public class InTouchDdeWrapper : IDisposable
    {
        private int DDE_TIMEOUT = 60000;

        private DdeClient _ddeClient;

        public InTouchDdeWrapper()
        {
            _ddeClient = new DdeClient("View", "Tagname");
        }

        ~InTouchDdeWrapper()
        {
            Dispose();
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            _ddeClient.Connect();
        }

        public string Read(string tagName)
        {
            return _ddeClient.Request(tagName, DDE_TIMEOUT).Replace("\0", "");
        }
```

Comment: `InTouchWrapper != InTouchDdeWrapper` -- please show the correct code.

Comment: hv u added reference of that dll in ASPX code?

Comment: There is only IntouchWrapper in my VS that is visible. It seems like InTouchDdeWrapper does not exist

Comment: Right click on TagBrowser -> Add Reference -> added the dll

Comment: Are you sure it's the correct dll you referenced? Try to open the exact referenced dll in a decompiler ([JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx), Reflector or [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler)) and see if it's the code you expect.

Comment: You're right It's different. Im installing a decompiler. Is there a simpler way to read it?

Comment: Well, .net dll's are compiled to IL, so if you're fine with reading that you can use ildasm.exe, otherwise you need something to decompile from IL to preferred .net language, like the mentioned decompilers above. That's simple enough =)

Comment: Sorry about this people, I've been assigned an old dll.

Comment: At least you solved the problem =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm putting this here in case somebody else would get the same problem:*

> Are you sure it's the correct dll you referenced? Try to open the
>   exact referenced dll in a decompiler ([JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) *free*,
>   [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) or [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) *free*) and see if it's the code you
>   expect.